# Determine clicked item and update aria-checked value in React

Tags: reactjs

```
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      this.data.map(item=> {
         <div aria-checked="true/false">{item}<div>
      })
    </div>
  )
}
```

For the above code, I want to write an onClick handler that changes the value of aria-checked to `true`, depending on the item selected/clicked on. If one item is selected, it's `aria-checked` will be `true` and the rest `false`.

I know I need a `checked` component state with a boolean type but I'm not sure how to do the handler logic.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You should show the component class and constructor. Also show how `this.data` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

you can do by `setAttribute`, here:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.data = ["hello", "world"];
}

handleClick = (e) => {
    const currentAriaChecked = (e.currentTarget.getAttribute("aria-checked") === 'true');
    e.currentTarget.setAttribute("aria-checked", !currentAriaChecked);
};

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {          
          this.data
            .map(item => (<div aria-checked="true" onClick={this.handleClick}>{item}</div>))
        }
      </div>
    );
}
```

---

### UPDATE

using typescript and react way

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {          
          this.data
            .map(item => (<Check>{item}</Check>))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

your component `check`

```
state = {
  isChecked: false
}

handleClick = (e) => {
  this.setState((prevState,props) => {
    return {isChecked: !prevState.isChecked }
  })
};

render() {
  return (
    <div aria-checked={this.state.isChecked} onClick={this.handleClick}>
      {this.props.children} {this.state.isChecked.toString()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

see [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-alewk7?file=Check.tsx).

Comment: is there a more react-y way of doing it?

Comment: yes, you can create `component` for ` aria-checked="true"` using `state` inside of it to handle toggle function.

Comment: also typescript error in the second line of handleClick `[ts] Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'` on `!currentAriaChecked`

Comment: I thought you are using `es6`. you need modify to suitable `typescript`

Comment: second param in `setAttribute` only takes a string. how can i make it take `currentAriaChecked` boolean?

Comment: see my update for typescript, or check https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-alewk7?file=Check.tsx

Comment: thanks. but this isn't quite what i was looking for. if i have 2 divs with `aria-checked` i want to be able to select one of the divs, turn its `aria-checked` to `true`. again if i select the other div, i want to `false` the `aria-checked` of the previous div but set it to `true` for the current one.

Comment: That is your turn